# Unable to Remove Border from Tk Window

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, perltk

I am using Perl and Tk to display a window with images inside. It cycles through images in the pattern of white background, black background, image (1280x800), repeat. The problem is that I need to be able to view the entire image. Tk is putting on a 2-pixel border on top of the images, including the black and white backgrounds. Here is my code...

```
use Tk;

# Create and configure the canvas:
my $canvas = $mw->Canvas( -cursor=>"crosshair", -background=>"black",
              -width=>1280, -height=>800 )->pack();
my $canvasWidth = 1280;
my $canvasHeight = 800;
my $blackRect = $canvas->createRectangle(0,0,$canvasWidth,$canvasHeight, -fill => "black", -tags => ['blackRect']);
my $whiteRect = $canvas->createRectangle(0,0,$canvasWidth,$canvasHeight, -fill => "white", -tags => ['whiteRect']);

# create a Photo object and one Button then we will reuse it.
my $shot = $canvas->Photo();
my $image = $canvas->createImage(0,0, -image => $shot, -anchor => "nw", -tags => ['image']);

# Remove the borders
$mw->overrideredirect(1);

# Loop through images
```

I know that `overrideredirect` gets rid of most of the extra stuff, but it still doesn't give me a *naked* window. I have tried adding `-borderwidth=>0` to the Canvas creation, and it changes nothing.

The border appears immediately and never goes away, not just when the first image is displayed.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the border on an image]

Can this border be removed? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
-highlightthickness => 0
```

to the `Canvas` call. This will remove the border which is used to show the currently focussed widget.

Comment: For the focus. You see the effect if you have two or more widgets and use the <Tab> key to move the focus around.